# Laravel how to check validate unique table two field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have tableA that there are 2 field

```
1. song_id
2. playlist_id
```

I want to check laravel validate unique func 
example: I have inserted data

```
id =>  1
song_id => 2
playlist_id => 34
```

then I have to insert data again I want to check that if 
 `playlist_id => 34` already inserted `song_id = 2` show message "already insert" but if `playlist_id => 34` insert `song_id = 3` allow insert

thank you for your help!

Comment: Sounds like you need a joint key of `song_id` and `playlist_id` to prevent duplicates on this table (which I assume is a pivot for a many-to-many between `songs` and `playlists`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the rule that need to apply. Tested with sample data and it works as desired.

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$playlist_id = request('playlist_id');

$rules = [
    'song_id' => Rule::unique('tableA')->where(function ($query) use ($playlist_id) {
        $query->where('playlist_id', $playlist_id);
    })
];
```

Sample condition

```
DB data
song_id     playlist_id
2           34
3           34

Request data
song_id     playlist_id     validation
2           34              fail
3           34              fail
4           34              success
2           35              success
3           35              success
```

Sample test code

```
$data = [
    'song_id' => 2,
    'playlist_id' => 34,
];

$playlist_id = $data['playlist_id'];

$validator = \Validator::make($data, [
    'song_id' => Rule::unique('tableA')->where(function ($query) use ($playlist_id) {
        $query->where('playlist_id', $playlist_id);
    })
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // handle failed validation
}
```

Comment: How can I call Rule  ?

Comment: I mean import Rule ?

Comment: @BrainMusic i've even added a sample test code to show you how. Do you know how to use validator? Post your existing validation code in your question. If not atleast post your controller method, so that i can show you how to.

Comment: I have added use Validator; but I got Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\Rule' not found

Comment: @BrainMusic add `use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;` at the top. Updated my answer to include that.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. it worked now. you saved me a lot of times.

Comment: @BrainMusic np, you can upvote the answer if works all good as expected

Comment: Oh I will upvote but for now they are not allow me yet. I will upvote for you