# laravel validation: unique two fields and array

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-8

Using laravel validation, I would like to ensure that a field is unique, but in an array context. (I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52902992/laravel-unique-field-validation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247440/laravel-how-to-check-validate-unique-table-two-field) but they don't address the array context.)

Let's suppose I have this html:

```
<input name="sites[1][id]"><input name="sites[1][site_mrn]">
<input name="sites[2][id]"><input name="sites[2][site_mrn]">
<input name="sites[3][id]"><input name="sites[3][site_mrn]">
```

In my validation rule, I want to ensure that each site's id is valid, and that the site_mrn is not blank, so I have:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'sites.*.site_mrn' => 'required|min:1',
        'sites.*.id' => 'exists:sites,id'
    ];
 }
```

So that part works. My problem is that I want to ensure that each pair of site `site_id` and `site_mrn` are unique in the `mpi_sites` table, but I don't know how to access each id/site_mrn pair in the input. I want to do something like this:

```
'sites.*' => Rule::unique('mpi_sites')->where(function ($q) {
        $q->where('site_id', $xxxxx)->where('site_mrn', $yyyyy);
    })
```

Comment: Did you check the after validation hook? It may be a possibility for you? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#after-validation-hook

Comment: Maybe this gives you inspiration on how to solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147584/laravel-validation-rules-if-value-exists-in-another-field-array